# May I run specific cells in the ipynb from cmd?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

dear friend!
I need to run the second cell in the ipynb (Jupyter notebook). I tried 'runipy' package, but it runs **all** ipynb like a script. 
Thank you for your attention!